# Ld on Mac Os Big Sur no option -T

Tags: assembly, operating-system, ld, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I am writing a basic Operating System and when I try to run link using ld I get the following error:

```
ld: unknown option: -T
```

My linking command is

```
ld -o bin/kernel.bin -T text 0x1000 bin/kernel.o --oformat binary
```

I also know that --oformat is an invalid option. I think it may be to do with using mac command line dev tools instead of binutils. However I do not think binutils is available for Mac Silicon. At least Ld is not. If anybody has the equivalent of these options for mac command line dev tools version of ld it would be greatly appreciated

-Winter_Ice

Comment: You should install GNU binutils from homebrew.

Comment: Homebrew Binutils for Mac silicon does not include the ld command

Comment: It may have the program under a different name, e.g. `ld.bfd`.